# Не могу обратиться к атрибуту класса Cython

Tags: python-3.x, cython

Решил перевести программу из Python3 в Cython, а тут такая проблема. Есть python-класс:

```py
class Device:
    def __init__(self, name, delay, tabl):
        self.name = name
        self.delay = delay
        self.speed_to = tabl

    def upd(self, u):
        self.speed_to.update(u)
        return 0
```

В Cython абсооютный новичок, поэтому перевёл в cython-класс по примерам, которые смог найти:

```py
cdef class Device:
    cdef str name 
    cdef long double delay
    cdef dict speed_to

    def __init__(self, str names, long double delays, dict tabls):
        self.name = names
        self.delay = delays
        self.speed_to = tabls

    cpdef upd(self, dict u):
        self.speed_to.update(u)
        return 0
```

Выглядит (для меня) так, что должно работать, но при обращении к любому атрибуту объекта вроде `Device('name', 123456, {1:2, 2:3}).name` выдаёт ошибку:
`AttributeError: 'cget_time.Device' object has no attribute 'name'`

Действительно, `dir()` этого объекта показывает `['__class__', ...magic methods..., '__subclasshook__', 'upd']`, то есть, атрибутов он не видит.

В чём проблема и как можно исправить?

Comment: Я думаю что вы не совсем правильно используете Cython.

Comment: @Александр говорю же, абсолютный новичок

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию поля *extension type* приватные и видимы только для методов. Это можно исправить с помощью модификаторов `readonly` и `public`:

```
cdef class Device:
    cdef public str name 
    ...
```